# WPF Custom binding Collection to non dependency property

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I've created my own custom binding class and added a property to it:

```
public BindingGroupCollection BindingGroups
{
    get { return validationResultGroup; }
    set { validationResultGroup = value; }
}

public class BindingGroupCollection : ObservableCollection<BindingGroup> { }
```

In my xaml class i declared the objects and collection:

```
<local:BindingGroup x:Key="BG1"/>
<local:BindingGroup x:Key="BG2"/>

<local:BindingGroupCollection x:Key="BindingGroups1">
   <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="BG1"/>
   <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="BG2"/>
</local:BindingGroupCollection>
```

And i want to use this in my binding eg.:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:CustomBinding BindingGroups={Binding Source={StaticResource BindingGroups1}}}"/>
```

But i get an error that the target is not a dependeny object. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, because a `Binding` isn't a `DependencyObject`, so it can't have have dependency properties.

However, in your case you don't need a binding, you can use the `StaticResource` directly:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:CustomBinding BindingGroups={StaticResource BindingGroups1}}"/>
```

Comment: Actually i've tried that too. However i get an error: "Unknown property 'ValidationResultGroups' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension."